# WCF REST Service return Method not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, rest

I have developed a WCF REST service & trying to test with Asp.net though works with wcf test client. This service maybe used by non-dot net client.

Am trying to create a test page in asp.net to verify this service via post. Currently, this service is hosted in my IIS

**In service:**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/MySVC?stringP={stringP}")]
        Stream MySVC(string stringP);
```

**In asp.net**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: "http://localhost/MySvcHost/MySVC.svc?stringP",
            cache: false,
            data: '[{stringP:"samplestring"}]',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            processData: true,
            success: function (msg) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
            }
        })
```

When I run test app, it goes to error block & Fiddler shows error "method not allowed" and shows as GET. I also see additional parameter (callback=) If I change "jsonp" to "json", it throws "transport error"

What shall I do?

**Update:**
service web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service
        name="Service.ParseService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" >
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web"
                  contract="Service.RestServiceInterface" name="BasicHttpBinding_RestServiceInterface2">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>   
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false" name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                   maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered"
                   bypassProxyOnLocal="false">
              <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="1024" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"></readerQuotas>

        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webEndpoint">
          <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
              helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding  name="BasicHttpBinding_RestServiceInterface2" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="1024" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint" address="http://localhost:14502/MySvcHost/MySVC.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_RestServiceInterface2" contract="MySVC.RestServiceInterface" name="BasicHttpBinding_RestServiceInterface2"/>
    </client>
```

Comment: I suspect the Stream return type, can you test it with another return type like string?

Comment: I suspect,it has nothing to do with Stream type. I changed to string and got same error in app. In fact, I tried accessing via hosted link..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 3:**

1. Add baseAddress to your web.config and remove everything that is not necessary:

   ```
   <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
       <service name="Service.ParseService"
                behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" >
         <endpoint address="" 
                   binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                   contract="Service.RestServiceInterface" name="BasicHttpBinding_RestServiceInterface2">
         </endpoint>
         <host>
           <baseAddresses>
             <add baseAddress="http://localhost:14502/MySvcHost/MySVC.svc"/>
           </baseAddresses>
         </host>
       </service>
     </services>
     <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
         </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
         <behavior name="webBehavior">
           <webHttp />
         </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
     </behaviors>

   </system.serviceModel>
   ```
2. Enable CORS, add to web.config at the service project such lines:

   ```
   <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
       </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
   ```
3. You have to have MySVC.svc in you project. Content should be like this:

   ```
   <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Service="Service.ParseService" %>
   ```
4. Interface should be:

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface RestServiceInterface
   {
      [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "MySVC")]
      Stream MySVC(string stringP); 

   }
   ```

   *Notice that interface name should start from I - IFileService, IMessageService...
   *Uri should identify resource and should be descriptive like these:

   ```
   POST: http://localhost/files/
   GET: http://localhost/files/1
   ```

   Read more at [REST API best practice](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api), [REST API design](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices/restful-api-design-second-edition)
5. Method implementation example:

   ```
   public Stream MySVC(string stringP)
   {
       var mem = new MemoryStream();
       var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
       ser.WriteObject(mem, stringP);

       mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

       return mem;
   }
   ```
6. Ajax call:

   ```
   $.ajax(
   {
       type: "POST",
       processData: false,
       contentType: "application/json",
       url: "http://localhost:14502/MySvcHost/MySVC.svc/MySVC",
       data: '"plnainString"',
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function (data) { alert(data); },
       error: function (data) { alert('error')); }
   })
   ```

   *Notice: if you make a call to the service from defferent machine then service is hosted you have to change localhost to the concrete machine name(or IP)
7. ONLY for debug purpose enable including exception stack trace to a fault message. Change web.config on the service project (includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"):

   ```
   <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I changed UriTemplate accordingly to your suggest but didn't work. I still see "no transport" error on ajax. I also added ServiceReference in asp.net app to test. I get different errror "There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/MySvcHost/MySVC.svc

Comment: error is "the remote server returned an unexpected response (400) bad request." though I can access service by URL. How can I send data via post?

Comment: as you can access it from url and not from application , maybe it's a CORS problem .

Comment: @user1480864 Agree, it seems the CORS issue. Please see updates: EDIT 1. Could you please also advice whether it works for fiddler?

Comment: @Legart I added line suggested by you in service web.config. I still see same error from service reference & "no transport" error in ajax. I can hit service url in browser but not sure how do I test POST functionality. Running out of ideas!

Comment: @user1480864 Download fiddler and try with it. Link: http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: @user1480864 Please find EDIT 2

Comment: Weird! I still see same stupid "no transport" error. And service ref in c# so same error. gosh! Even fiddler doesn't capture call to service via ajax or c# call

Comment: After adding this line in jquer jQuery.support.cors = true; I see "404 error". The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

Comment: Started rewriting based on your suggestions. will revert to you.